# access back-end ecs container only from front-end ecs container

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a problem with limiting access to back-end container in my project.
My goal is to have front-end ecs container open for client and using nginx reverse proxy redirect any requests with "/api" route to back-end container. However I don't want to allow any access besides the one described earlier to my back-end.
I was trying to locate back-end container in private subnet and connect it to front-end but it didn't work.

BACKEND_ORIGIN var is stored in task definition as key-value pair, later I'll use separate service to store it. Was trying to store backend IP in there.

I added below part of my .conf nginx file.

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name localhost;

set_by_lua_block $backend_origin {
  return os.getenv('BACKEND_ORIGIN')
}

location /api {
  proxy_pass $backend_origin;
  proxy_redirect off;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_buffering off;
}

location / {
  root /usr/share/openresty/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Are both containers in the same ECS task or separate tasks? And these are running on Fargate?

Comment: I have separate task for back-end and front-end. 1 cluster, 2 task definitions, 2 services.
Yup, these are running on fargate.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using the same domain for both frontend and backend?

I think the easiest way you can do is use an internal ALB for the backend and use that ALB domain for redirecting. The new ALB will only allow traffic from frontend.

Comment: At the moment I'm working only on IP addresses but yea, I'll have the same domain for both containers. Can you please explain a bit more how should I configure alb for back-end?

Comment: So instead of 1, you should have 2 alb, 1 public alb for FE and 1 internal alb for BE, and define the target groups so that the public traffic will call FE through the first alb, and the FE will call BE through the second alb.